# Nvidia Colorprofile Enforcer App , needs work to detect and apply separate Profile depending on Display Switched to

Tags: nvidia, display, profile

so i found this colorprofile forcing app but it only supports one display not multiple displays, anybody able to make it so it detects multiple displays , so for example if i switch from one display to another it will force a separate colorprofile for that display aka display tied profiles , really need this , would be a huge favor thanks.

this is the link to said app> https://bitbucket.org/CalibrationTools/calibration-tools/downloads/

p.s , i wouldve contacted app author but theres no username nor contact info to do so .

Comment: anybody able to come up with a solution would appreciate for sure

Comment: yeah , still would love a fix

Comment: still would appreciate if someone would be able to accomplish said request , really need this

Comment: ok well , ive gotten it solved , thanks